# How to increase lighting in scene?

Tags: swift, scenekit, swift5

I'm trying to light up a basic model I downloaded from Mixamo.

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Ch45_nonPBR.dae")!

// create and add a camera to the scene
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

// place the camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 40, z: 110)

// create and add a light to the scene
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light!.type = .omni
lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 50, z: 50)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

// create and add an ambient light to the scene
let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.white
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
```

At present the camera is too close to the model. But if I change the z-value from 110, all I see is black. I imagine this has something to do with lighting. What should my lighting be so that I can see my model even if I change the z-value of my camera to a higher value so I can see the model from far away ?

EDIT: For example, right now you can see at this distance, part of the leg is not visible:

[image]

If I move further away, the whole model won't be visible!!

EDIT: For example, how do I edit the lighting so it looks just like in the Mixamo preview on their website:

[image]

I would like to move the camera far enough away so I can see the whole model on screen.

Comment: It’s probably being clipped, increase the zFar of the camera.

Comment: @JamesP You Sir, are a genius! Feel free to turn your comment into an answer for glory and bonus points!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCNCamera` has a `zFar` property, the default value is 100, any surface further away from the camera than this is clipped to improve performance. In your screenshot the leg is the furthest part of the model from the camera so gets clipped first, and as you move further away the whole model is clipped.
You can just increase the `zFar` to a number suitable for your scene.